# show my meeting in SharePoint calendar list

Tags: 2016, mysite

my manager ask me to show his meeting in his calendar list ! I don't know, how can do it

is it easy and possible to sync my meeting from outlook to a calendar in my personal mysite?

if yes please tell me how?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office Integration with SharePoint is one-to-one; meaning you can link your calendar no problem, but others will not be able to use your link to view or connect their stuff to the connection.  There are ways you can move around this with workflows and custom actions.  For a simple solution, just connect his calendar view to his outlook calendar from the ribbon.  Then you can work on a more dynamic and comprehensive solution to apply to all meetings for all users if you like.  Go with the simple first and then move on from there.  I hope this helps.  Good luck!